# ¿Alguien sabe por qué siempre dice que el email no es correcto, aunque sí? Si todo está correcto, funciona

Tags: java, regex, validación

Resulta que estoy usando if-else if para validaciones. No me da errores en el código, pero al validar siempre dice que el email no es correcto. He hecho pruebas poniendo mal el nick, mal el password, etc... y siempre dice que el email no es correcto. Una vez está todo bien, sí funciona

```
createNewUserButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                //Pattern para validar el email
                Pattern pattern1 = Pattern.compile("(?:[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\\.[a-z0-9!#$%" +
                "&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*|\"(?:[\\x01-\\x08\\x0b\\x0c\\x0e-\\x1f\\x21\\x23-\\x5b\\x5d-\\x" +
                "7f]|\\\\[\\x01-\\x09\\x0b\\x0c\\x0e-\\x7f])*\")@(?:(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9]" +
                ")?\\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?|\\[(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]" +
                "?)\\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?|[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9]:(?:[\\x01-\\x08" +
                "\\x0b\\x0c\\x0e-\\x1f\\x21-\\x5a\\x53-\\x7f]|\\\\[\\x01-\\x09\\x0b\\x0c\\x0e-\\x7f])+)\\])");

                //Pattern para validar el nick y el contraseña
                Pattern pattern2 = Pattern.compile("^.[^ ]{4,20}$");

                //Recogida de email, nick y contraseña
                Matcher matcherEmail = pattern1.matcher(newEmail.getText().toString());
                Matcher matcherNick = pattern2.matcher(newNick.getText().toString());
                Matcher matcherPassword = pattern2.matcher(newPassword.getText().toString());

                //Validación
                if (matcherEmail.find()
                & matcherNick.find()
                & matcherPassword.find()
                & newPassword.getText().toString().equals(repeatNewPassword.getText().toString())){

                    serviceExecution("http://miip/buksu/insertUsers.php");

                } else if (!matcherEmail.find()) {

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "La dirección de correo electrónico no es correcta.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    newEmail.getText().clear();

                } else if (!matcherNick.find()) {

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "El nick tiene que tener entre 5 y 20 caracteres y ningún espacio.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    newNick.getText().clear();

                } else if (!matcherPassword.find()) {

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "La contraseña tiene que tener entre 5 y 20 caracteres y ningún espacio.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    newPassword.getText().clear();
                    repeatNewPassword.getText().clear();

                } else {

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Las contraseñas deben coincidir.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    newPassword.getText().clear();
                    repeatNewPassword.getText().clear();

                }

            }
        });`
```

Comment: Has probado a debugearlo? Comprado tienes bien el match?

Comment: Probaste si el regex funciona?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eso pasa porque el método `find()` del Matcher busca la siguiente ocurrencia de ese patrón. En el primer `if` busca la primera ocurrencia, luego cuando se vuelve a llamar por ejemplo en `if (!matcherEmail.find())`, `find()` busca la siguiente ocurrencia y retorna falso porque ya no hay otra.

Lo que puedes hacer es invertir el orden de las condiciones para llamar `find()` solo una vez:

```
if (!matcherEmail.find()) {

       Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "La dirección de correo electrónico no es correcta.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       newEmail.getText().clear();

    } else if (!matcherNick.find()) {

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "El nick tiene que tener entre 5 y 20 caracteres y ningún espacio.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    newNick.getText().clear();

    } else if (!matcherPassword.find()) {

     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "La contraseña tiene que tener entre 5 y 20 caracteres y ningún espacio.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     newPassword.getText().clear();
     repeatNewPassword.getText().clear();

  } else if(!newPassword.getText().toString()
            .equals(repeatNewPassword.getText().toString())) {

     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Las contraseñas deben coincidir.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     newPassword.getText().clear();
     repeatNewPassword.getText().clear();

   } else {
   serviceExecution("http://miip/buksu/insertUsers.php");
}
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias! Aclarar que hay un pequeño error en el pattern del email, y es que cuando incluyes "//" en cualquier IDE, da error. He leído que es porque es lo usado para poner comentario jajajaja y no había caído. Por lo demás, perfecto. Ya funciona bien. Muchísimas gracias! Me he llevado varias horas haciendo todo tipo de pruebas :)